# Criar versões de serviço rest

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, versionamento, jersey

Estou criando serviços rest com Java (Jersey).

Este serviço tende a crescer e evoluir, e poderá sofrer mudanças em rotinas existentes, portanto, acredito que o melhor caminho seria criar versões em produção para que os clients não quebrem com as mudanças.

Atualmente faço o deploy do sistema no Tomcat, sendo o acesso através de uma URL exemplo:

```
http://www.meudominio.com.br:8180/minhaApi/recurso
```

Acredito que o ideal seria algo como:

```
http://www.meudominio.com.br:8180/minhaApi/v1/recurso
http://www.meudominio.com.br:8180/minhaApi/v2/recurso
```

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Você não tá colocando a carroça na frente dos bois? Se nem lançou a primeira versão ainda, por que se preocupar com a segunda?

Comment: Porque uma segunda fase já está prevista e eu sei como as coisas acontecem. Vai chegar um pedido "simples" de alteração num recurso que já está em produção.

Comment: Aí **eu acho** que é um pequeno erro de conceito seu. Tem certeza que esse "pedido 'simples' de alteração num recurso" vai ter que ser lançado numa versão (major) diferente? Claro que é você que decide quando a versão da sua API vai mudar, mas eu acho que esse tipo de versão (pra chegar a mudar o endpoint) tem que ser uma mudança grande na API. Eu diria que isso é só quando você reescreve a API.

Comment: Meu medo é (suposição mode on): terei um app mobile rodando em n usuários. De repente preciso modificar alguma coisa num recurso que  venha a quebrar a utilização nesses clientes. Eu não queria ter que alterar, subir o novo app para a store e obrigar todos os usuários a fazer a atualização. Se eu tiver esse controle eu não preciso forçar nada, pois todo mundo continuará acessando pela versão anterior, entendeu?

Answer (score -1):

Versões de uma aplicação não são gerenciadas programaticamente, e sim através de sistemas de controle de versão (GIT, SVN, ...). Quando você precisa fechar uma versão que não deve ser modificada e é estável você cria uma tag daquela versão. Assim, você pode gerar o seu artefato publicado em produção a partir dessa tag e evoluir teu código sem medo que ele quebre o que está sendo utilizado pelo cliente. A cada nova versão estável, uma nova tag seria criada e assim você evoluiria teu projeto.

Caso você não tenha experiência com controle de versão, recomendo o uso do git: https://git-scm.com/

Comment: Eu já utilizo GIT. O meu problema é versionar o endpoint.

Comment: Mas o endpoint está nos arquivos de configuração, que por sua vez são versionados. Não tem como fazer essa separação, e nem faz sentido.