# Versionamento de API REST. Existe uma maneira de se fazer e qual seria a melhor opção?

Tags: api, rest, versionamento

Atualmente desenvolvo APIs de integração com serviços internos à nossa empresa e em um futuro próximo teremos a oportunidade de disponibilizar algumas de nossas APIs para parceiros externos.

Sugir a ideia de um versionamento de API em um brainstorm da equipe.

Atualmente sou contra versionar a API, mas lendo mais sobre o assunto e entendendo a motivação da equipe em versionar a API, eu pergunto. Existe uma melhor maneira para se versionar uma API? É uma boa ideia versionar a API? Eu penso em focar em um "contrato" uma wiki definindo tanto a API quanto os inputs e outputs ou mesmo um excel daria conta do recado.

Já vi falarem de versionamento no path do recurso, no cabeçalho Accept e um custom header Version ou algo assim. Qual a experiência de vocês neste assunto?

Comment: Tmb tenho esta dúvida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138956/criar-vers%C3%B5es-de-servi%C3%A7o-rest

Comment: Estou imaginando que não há uma boa e idiomática maneira de se fazer este tipo de versionamento.

Comment: Uma forma que achei é fazer o deploy mudando o nome da aplicação (ex: minhapp_v1, minhaapp_v2, etc). Mas acho que deve haver uma solução melhor.

Comment: com certeza kkkkkkk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode estar fazendo uso de um VCS (do inglês, Version control systems) para gerenciar suas versões no caso [GIT](https://git-scm.com/) (prefiro) ou [SVN](https://subversion.apache.org/), podemos assumir que a mudança de estrutura de uma api seria uma nova branch, e toda versão disponibilizada uma TAG, assim você pode controle sobre a alteração de código e sobre as versões de sua aplicação.

Para disponibilização para seus clientes, você pode fazer o uso de subpastas ou então de subdomínios diferentes. Exemplo `api-v1.meusistema.com.br`, `api-v2.meusistema.com.br`. Eu faria com subpastas, `meusistema.com.br/api-v1`, `meusistema.com.br/api-v2` mas ai vai de cada um, faça da maneira que melhor lhe agrade.

Uma dica é você procurar como outras empresas trabalham, assim pode se basear em padrões já utilizados e que funcionam para fazem a disponibilização da API.

O [Moip](https://dev.moip.com.br/v2.0/docs) por exemplo controla por pastas, exemplo `api.moip.com.br/v2` ou `api.moip.com.br/v1`.